# How to extract data from an API and create an array to send to the another API in Jmeter?

Tags: arrays, json, api, jmeter

Example:

API A:

```
{
   "customer":[
      {
         "name":"Jane",
         "phone":"9999999",
         "email":"jane@test.com"
      },
      {
         "name":"John",
         "phone":"8888888",
         "email":"john@test.com"
      },
      {
         "name":"Joe",
         "phone":"7777777",
         "email":"Joe@test.com"
      }
   ]
}
```

Using the JSON extractor, I want to get the names of all the customers
so: Jane, John, Joe

How do I get these values and turn them into an array

`[{"name":"Jane", "name":"John", "name":"Joe"}]`

And pass it onto the next API?

Note: That it has to be dynamic so API A could show different 2 names or 1 name or more and needs to be adjusted into the array

Comment: Map them... code: `input.customer.map(v => v.name)` try it in chrome console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your `[{"name":"Jane", "name":"John", "name":"Joe"}]` is not a valid JSON, you can [check it yourself](https://jsonlint.com/):

[image]

so I strongly doubt that this is the string you need to generate.

So if you **really** need to construct this value you can do something like:

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which returns this "customers" data
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def response = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())
   def payload = new StringBuilder()
   payload.append('[{')
   0.upto(response.customer.size - 1, { index ->
       payload.append('"name": "').append(response.customer[index].name).append('"')
       if (index != response.customer.size - 1) {
           payload.append(',')
       }
   })
   payload.append('}]')
   vars.put('payload', payload as String)
   ```
3. Refer the generated value as `${payload}` where required

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [JsonSlurper](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)